# Why are smooth exhaustion functions proper maps?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth manifolds* an exhaustion function of a topological space $M$ is defined as a continuous function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ is compact in $M$. Later in the proof of Whitney's embedding theorem it is used that such a function is *proper*, i.e. that the pre-image $f^{-1}(K)$ for any compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is again compact in $M$. I can't see why every exhaustion function needs to be proper. My approach: Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be compact, then $K$ is bounded and thus included in a set $(-\infty, c]$ and therefore $f^{-1}(K)$ is a subset of the compact set $f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$. It remains to show that $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed, but I can't think of an appropriate argument. Since it's not even shown in the book it's probably very easy to see that the claim is true, but I still have some gaps in my knowledge of point-set topology... Any hint/solution is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the continuous preimage of a closed set always closed? This follows from the fact that if $f:X\to Y$, then $X\setminus f^{-1}(K) = f^{-1}(Y\setminus K)$

Comment: @MPW, wow... of course, yes. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are using the characterization of compact sets in $\Bbb R$, but $f^{-1}(K)$ is a subset of $M$.

Comment: @Darsen: I actually wanted to use this property: https://planetmath.org/closedsubsetsofacompactsetarecompact For this i need to make sure that $f^{-1}(K)$ is included in a compact set in $M$. True, I used boundedness of $K$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to come up with a set inclusion for this. Is this a mistake? Maybe my wording was just a bit off, i apologize.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then it is correct. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(C) \in M$ is closed whenever $C$ is closed in the codomain.

Your argument may be to take $K$ compact subset of $(-\infty, c]$. Hence it is closed, (since compact sets are closed) and by continuity of $f$, also $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $M$. Since $f$ is an exhaustion function, then a closed subset of a compact set is compact and the result follows.